# Ajax to load a local json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have already checked every problem here about how to use ajax to load a local json file, but nothing is working with me:

This is my javascript code to display a local json file:

```
  // rooms selection code


     document.querySelectorAll('.select-room').forEach(p => {
        p.onclick = () => {
          var newRoom = p.innerHTML;
          if (newRoom==room) {
            msg =`You are already in ${room} room.`;
            printSysMsg(msg);
          } else {
            leaveRoom(room);
            joinRoom(newRoom);
            room=newRoom;
            loadChat();
                  }
      }
    });

function loadChat(room) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "chat.json",
    dataType: "json",
    method: "GET"
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data.room);
  });
}
```

This is the server side code in python, flask to write in json file:

```
@socketio.on("message")
def message(data):
    msg = data["msg"].rstrip()
    username= data["username"]
    time_stamp = strftime('%b-%d %I:%M%p', localtime())
    room = data["room"]
    message = [time_stamp,msg,username]

    if room in Messages_by_Room.keys():
        if (len(Messages_by_Room[room])<= 2):
            Messages_by_Room [room].append(message)
        else:
            Messages_by_Room[room].pop(0)
            Messages_by_Room[room].append(message)
    else:
        Messages_by_Room.update({room: message})

    with open('./chat.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(Messages_by_Room,f, indent=2)

    send({"msg": msg, "username": username,"time_stamp": time_stamp}, room= data['room'])
```

The json file is stored in the same place of the javascript file.

The error keeps telling me "jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/chat.json 404 (NOT FOUND)"

Can you help me to read a local json file by ajax or another way, please?

Comment: where is `chat.json` located relative to the page that is performing that ajax request? not relative to the javascript file, but relative to the page (the html file)

Comment: I placed the json file next to the template html and i keep receiving the same error not found, so i placed it next to js file maybe this was the problem, but it seems not! So i could not figure out what was the problem.

Comment: `chat.json` should be in the *www* root - whatever that is on your system

Comment: I am using python to write this file, do you mean that it should be next to application.py???

Comment: I placed in the root but i keep receiving the same error not found????

Answer (score 0):

Try `./chat.json`

sometimes your web browser cache your assets, therefore, your code is not updated in your browser.

Comment: I am clearing the cache everytime and i tried to used ./chat.json but still the same error!! I don't know what is the problem?

Comment: what server solution are your using? Maybe your server is not accepting JSON.

Comment: I have updated my post and include the codes in both server side and js file.

Comment: Is your HTML file in the same path as your JS and JSON file?

Comment: No. Html files in a folder Templates, and Js files in Static folder. Json file in the root as the Application.py ; python file.

Comment: Try specifying the path for .JSON file from your HTML file. use `../` for moving up the path.

Comment: I tried this: http://127.0.0.1:5000/chat.json but not found either!